# node.js Trying to set multiple variables from multiple requests

Tags: node.js

So I've been trying to set a global variable from inside a request, but seem to be getting nothing. The code I'm using

A username for testing is test2 after `username=`

```
     var forSearching =  "test2"; 
     var name = "";

     console.log(forSearching);
     request("http://mercsystem.esy.es/get.php?username=" + forSearching, function(err, res, body) 
     {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            var main = JSON.parse(body);
            if (main.success == "false")
            {
                message.reply("Sorry, invalid user!")
            }
            else
            {
              name = main.Username
            }
    });
```

Comment: Please format your code a little better, as it's currently written, it's hard to tell where blocks begin and end.

Comment: It's not too clear what you're trying to achieve. As far as I can see, if your request sis successful, `name` will be set to the username returned in the response. But that's not much use to you, since it won't be set until the request returns (so if you tried to reference it outside the request callback it would likely still be undefined)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I improved it a little bit if it's easier now.

Comment: @TomJenkins I'm not quite at the level to understand how to use callbacks, although I did read many questions similar but none really seemed to be an exact copy of mine.

Comment: there is no clear indentation at all in that code.

Comment: @MichaelBoyd if you're going to do anything much in Node you'll need to understand asynchronicity. You may be used to e.g. PHP where calls typically "block" (i.e. the next line of code won't run until the previous one has completed). In this instance, the callback function you have passed to `request()` *will not be called until the server at mercsystem.esy.es responds*

Comment: @aschmid00 There is if you've read. I'm trying to set a global variable from inside a request.

Comment: @MichaelBoyd no there is no clear indentation still in my opinion.

Comment: @aschmid00 It's still pretty clear what I'm asking help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert a `console.log(name)` right after you set the value, you will see that the value is set just fine.

The issue is likely one of timing.  `request()` is an asynchronous operation.  That means calling `request()` starts the asynchronous operation, then the rest of your code continues to run to completion and then, some time LATER, the callback gets called with the final asynchronous results.

Though you don't show where you are trying to use the `name` variable, you are probably checking the value of this global variable before the callback has been called and thus before the value has been set.

In node.js, what you are doing is not how you use asynchronous results.  It will never work reliably (or at all).  Instead, the only place to use your asynchronous result is in the callback itself or in some function you call from the callback and pass the result to.

```
var forSearching = "test2";

console.log("begin");
request("http://mercsystem.esy.es/get.php?username=" + forSearching, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log("in request() callback");
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    var main = JSON.parse(body);
    if (main.success == "false") {
        message.reply("Sorry, invalid user!")
    } else {
        var name = main.Username
        console.log(name);          // value shows fine here
        // use the name variable here or call some function and pass
        // the name variable to it
    }
});
console.log("after request() call");

// You cannot use the name value here (even if it was in a global) because
// the async callback has not yet been called
```

If you ran this code with the `console.log()` statement I've added, you would see this sequence of events:

```
 begin
 after request() call
 in request() callback
```

From this sequence, you can see that code after your `request()` call runs BEFORE the async callback runs.  Thus, you cannot use your `name` variable there, even if it is in a global.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I'm trying to do is set other variables(that was just one to show what Im trying to do), and then once they're all done have it sent back in a message.

Comment: @MichaelBoyd - As I said, you can't do it that way.  You have to continue your code logic in the callback itself.  Whatever your next step after getting the result of the `request()` must be in the callback (or you can call a function from the callback to continue).

Comment: Do you think there is any way to basically wait until it's completed?

Comment: @MichaelBoyd - No, you can't just make the Javascript interpreter wait for the result.  You have to learn how to code asynchronously in node.js.   node.js does non-blocking, asynchronous I/O.  You have to learn how to code with it.  Personally,  I use promises for all my asynchronous coding because they are a tool that helps you do this more easily, but that is another thing for you to learn.  It may seem extremely unintuitive at the moment, but you will learn it and it will become second nature at some point.  There are lots of tutorials on the web.